# VirtualboxでホストOSと仮想OSのファイルやフォルダの共有

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

ホストOSはWindows11、仮想OSはVirtualBoxを使いxubuntuを利用して学習しています。

- ホストOSで文書をコピーして、仮想OSのテキストファイルにペースト。
- あるいは、ホストOSと仮想OSでドキュメントやフォルダを共有する。

と言ったことは不可能なのでしょうか？

仮想OSを作成する際に、「クリップボードの共有」、「ドラッグ&ドロップ」は
「双方向」に設定しているのですがうまくいきません。

またホストOSと仮想OSでフォルダを共有出来ればもう少し便利に使えるかなと思っています。

学習用教材や、インターネットなどのに書いてあった方法のまま設定しています。

上記2点、ホストOSと仮想OS間でクリップボードやドラッグ＆ドロップをする方法。
あるいは共有フォルダを作成する方法などご存じでしたら教えて下さい。

初心者です。よろしくお願いします。

[image: xubuntu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キャプチャ画像にも写っていますが、ゲスト OS の設定画面で「共有フォルダー」を追加するのが簡単です。(ゲスト OS 側で Samba を構築する方法もあります)

この機能を使うことで、ホスト OS 側の任意のフォルダを、ゲスト OS からも参照することができます。

なお、 VirtualBox の共有フォルダー機能を利用する場合、ゲスト OS に予め Guest Additions をインストールしておく必要があります。

参考:
[共有フォルダ設定 - VirtualBox Mania](https://vboxmania.net/%E5%85%B1%E6%9C%89%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A/)

Comment: どうもありがとうございました